# Edit video using QT and QML on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, qt, video, qml

Is it possible to edit a video using QT/QML for Android and iOS?

I would like to be able to trim a video from timeX to timeY and add (if possible) a watermark.

I did some research but I didn't find anything good.

Answer (score 0):

All Qt has to offer regarding video is contained in the [Qt Multimedia](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-index.html) library.

This library is not designed to do video editing, so you will have nothing out of the box.

However, it *might* be possible to combine `QMediaRecorder` and `QMediaPlayer` to trim a video. And you also have access to video frames: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/videooverview.html#working-with-low-level-video-frames

I am not sure you will be able to do what you want using only Qt Multimedia, you might be better off using a dedicated video editing library. Maybe you can take a look at OpenShot, it is an open source video editor. The user interface is built with Qt and the video editing functions are in a separate library: [libopenshot](https://github.com/OpenShot/libopenshot).

Comment: Your idea is not bad about the QMediaRecorder and QMediaPlayer. I tried but it's not working.. or I dont know how to do it. State and error seems ok but the isAvalable() always return false.
In the QMediaRecorder, there is this comment: 
The QMediaRecorder class is a high level media recording class. It's not intended to be used alone but for accessing the media recording functions of other media objects, like QRadioTuner, or QCamera.
So im not sure it's possible.
I will have a look on the libopenshot, thanks.